# remote SVN merge

Tags: svn, merge, branch

When trying to merge a branch into trunk with

```
svn merge "$SVN_ROOT/trunk@HEAD" "$SVN_ROOT/branches/foo@HEAD"
```

I get the following error:

```
svn: '/' is not a working copy
```

Do I need a working copy?

Comment: Oh, I should have read the docs: "Apply the differences between two sources to a working copy path."; but is it possible to do this remotely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need a local checkout.
I recommend the following steps:

```
svn co https://foo.bar.com/subversion/project/trunk project
cd project
svn merge https://foo.com/subversion/project/trunk https://foo.com/subversion/project/branches/DEV
svn st
```

If there are any conflicts, you can resolve them with:

```
svn resolve
```

Commit the changes:

```
svn commit -m "Merged DEV to trunk."
```

Answer (score 3):

Note what `svn merge` command does:

svn merge — Apply the differences between two sources to **a working copy path.**

The form you are using is

```
svn merge sourceURL1[@N] sourceURL2[@M] [WCPATH]
```

[WCPATH] is optional and when omitted it is assumed to be `.` ( current directory). That is what's happening in your case.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do - sorry. It's possible that the merge will throw up conflicts that you'll need to manually edit and resolve (plus I've a feeling the diff / merge code is only in the svn client not the server - not 100% sure about that, though). So you'll need to check-out and make the merge locally:

```
svn co "$SVN_ROOT/trunk"
cd trunk
svn merge "$SVN_ROOT/branches/foo"
svn commit
```

etc.